# Getting data from OMDB Api using Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

Hey guys I am using the OMDB API to get the list of movies. I get the data in the console but I cant loop through it to show it in the UI. It just returns an empty.

```
export class example {
  movies: Movie[];
  search: string;

  constructor(private service: MovieService) {}

  getMovies(): void {
    this.service.get(this.search).then((result) => {
      this.movies = [result];
      console.log(result)
    });
  }
}
```

When I console log the data I am getting this:
[image]
in my HTML component I loop through it like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let movie of movies">
<div>{{movie.Title}}<span>{{movie.Rated}}</span></div>
</div>
```

But this is not working. It just doesnt do anything.

Can someone help me please? I would really appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: Please, try to change the `this.movies = [result];` to `this.movies = result.Search;` and lets see what will happening

Comment: it says Search does not exists on Type movie.

Comment: as I can see on your "print", the `result` object has a property called `Search` that is an array with the data you are looking for. You need to pass this value to your `movies` list.

Comment: How would i pass it?

Comment: Your `service.get(...)` is not returning a `Movie` object. It's returning an object like: `{Search: Movie[]; totalResults: number; Response: boolean}`. You need to change this signature. Just to make a quickly check try to use this: `this.movies = (<any>result).Search;`

Comment: it worked, i really appreciate your help. Now i am getting all the list of the movies. but like movie.Title or movie.Rated shows empty

Comment: Great! Let me prepare an answer, so you can mark it as correct!

Comment: I cant see the `Rated` property on your print. I can see only: `Poster`, `Title`, `Type`, `Year` and `imdbID`. The code still not working to you?

Comment: Oh okay i figured it out. Just those properties work, the rest doesnt work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look on your `MovieService` class. The `get(...)` function needs to return a promise with an "typed" object like:

```
{
    Search: Movie[]; 
    totalResults: string;
    Response: string;
}
```

and not a `Movie` object. The current typing is wrong. To **check it**, just try to change the line:

```
this.movies = [result];
```

to:

```
this.movies = (<any>result).Search;
```